# html textbox positioned incorrectly?

Tags: html, css

My html/css code interferes with my **HTML/CSS** drop down menu

i have included my html/css search in my Navagation bar this time but the search box it down below the navagation bar . my jsfiddle will help you out more then the code below. the code below is sloppy because i copyed it from another one of my questions

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TonnaJacob/ZWf5C/)**

**HTML**

```
<title>Mingamez.com</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
</head>
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span><img style="height: 35px;width:75;"     src="images/logo_image.png" alt="website logo"/></span></a></li>
 <li class='has-sub'><a href='#' style="align:right;"><span>Products</span></a>
    <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
           <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Item</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     </ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="#Search..."><span>
  <form method="get" action="search" id="advsearch">
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
  </form>
    </span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
/** Body */
body{
background-color:#9FBAC4;
}
/** Advanced css menu */
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index:-1;}
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index:-1;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0; z-index:-1;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none; z-index:-1;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none; z-index:-1;}
#cssmenu { height: 62px; background-color: rgb(35,35,35); box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}
#cssmenu { position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; z-index:-1;}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
   float: left;
   margin-right: 35px;
   margin-left: 35px;
   position: relative;
  }
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
   color: rgb(160,160,160);
   font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 70px;
   padding: 15px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
    -o-transition: color .15s;
       transition: color .15s;
}
 #cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {color: rgb(250,250,250); }
 #cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
   opacity: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
   padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
   background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
   text-align: left;
   position: absolute;
   top: 55px;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -90px;
   width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
    -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
       box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
 }

 #cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
   opacity: 1;
   top: 68px;
   visibility: visible;
 }
 #cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
   content: '';
   display: block;
   border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 10px;
   position: absolute;
   top: -20px;
   left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}
#cssmenu ul ul a{
   color: rgb(50,50,50);
   font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
   font-size: 13px;
   background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
   padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
   display: block;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
    -o-transition: background-color .1s;
       transition: background-color .1s;
}
 #cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: rgb(240,240,240);}
 #cssmenu ul ul ul {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: -14px;
   right: 206px;
   padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
   background-color: rgb(250,250,250);
   text-align: left;
   width: 160px;
-webkit-transition: all .83s;
  -moz-transition: all .83s;
    -o-transition: all .83s;
       transition: all .83s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
       box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: -170px; visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
   background-color: rgb(0,133,143);
   color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
/** Advanced Css Search Box */
#advsearch {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 0px;
}
#advsearch input[type="text"] {
background: url(images/search-dark.png) no-repeat 10px 6px #fcfcfc;
border: 1px solid #d1d1d1;
font: bold 12px Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
color: #bebebe;
width: 150px;
padding: 6px 15px 6px 35px;
-webkit-border-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 20px;
text-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-moz-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
-o-transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}
#advsearch input[type="text"]:focus {
width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: don't forget your `input:focus{ ouline:none; }` otherwise inputs like that look bad in chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `line-height:70px` that is messing your `<a>` tag. Your form is inside the `<a>` tag, I think you should avoid that...

```
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
color: rgb(160, 160, 160);
font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 70px;
```

Comment: is it `line-heigh:70px` or `line-height:70px` , please address

Comment: with "t" thanks for correcting it. In the CSS i posted, the las line. I edited my answer also

Comment: i removed the <a> thanks, now that is removed i need the textbox to be 18px down

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TonnaJacob/HCwPt/1/  <~ this is what i did to get it working thanks

Comment: @Sergio i am having another problem aligning my "products" menu to the right http://jsfiddle.net/TonnaJacob/eKyLC/ theres a JSFIDDLE i would ask in another question but i dont want to be flagged for to many questions

Comment: ok, where do you want it. On the right side of the search field?